# No entiendo cual es la diferencia en mi código de Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Tenía un problema: no recibía una actualización de estado en mi función Compose de Jetpack. Tenía que hacer clic dos veces para que se actualizara y no se comportaba como esperaba:

```kotlin
// Esta función está en mi función compose

Image(
    imageVector = if (monumentVo.isFavorite) {
         Icons.Default.Favorite
    } else {
         Icons.Default.FavoriteBorder
    },
    contentDescription = "",
    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
         monumentVo.isFavorite = !monumentVo.isFavorite
         homeViewModel.setMonumentFavorite(monumentVo)
}

// Esta es la data class de mi objeto

data class MonumentVo(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val title: String,
    val location: CoordinatesVo,
    val description: String,
    val image: String,
    val author: String,
    var isFavorite: Boolean = false
)

// Este método actualiza el estado en el ViewModel

fun setMonumentFavorite(monument: MonumentVo) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        InsertMonumentFavoriteUseCase().insertMonumentFavorite(
            monument.copy(isFavorite = monument.isFavorite)
        )
        monumentsState.value = GetAllMonumentsFromLocalUseCase()
            .map { it.toVo() }
        }
}
```

El caso es que así no funciona. No actualiza el estado, pero si elimino la línea dentro de la función composable que dice `monumentVo.isFavorite = !monumentVo.isFavorite`, sí funciona, pero con ella puesta no, ¿por qué?

Comment: Donde defines `monumentVo`?

Comment: monumentVo me viene del listado de elementos que le pasó a un LazyColumn

Answer (score 0):

Voy a responderme a mi mismo ya que era un comportamiento que no estaba teniendo en cuenta y creo que puede ayudar a alguien más en el futuro.

Primeros vamos a partir de la base de que **yo tenía un StateFlow convertido a estado de compose gracias al método collectAsState dentro de la vista.**

Una caracteristica que tiene es que **si los datos que tiene almacenados son exactamente los mismos que le estamos pasando, esta no se va a actualizar**, por eso se juega con la función `copy`

Entonces, yendo a mi código, yo estoy haciendo dentro del método clickable un seteo a la variable mutable isFavorite y después le paso ese monument al viewModel que es el que guarda en base de datos:

```kotlin
fun setMonumentFavorite(monument: MonumentVo) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        InsertMonumentFavoriteUseCase().insertMonumentFavorite(
            monument.copy(isFavorite = monument.isFavorite)
        )
        monumentsState.value = GetAllMonumentsFromLocalUseCase()
            .map { it.toVo() }
        }
}
```

Aquí ya estaba haciendo algo que no tenía sentido, pues al insertar en base de datos estaba guardando una copia del monument, seteando exactamente el mismo valor que ya tenía.

Si recuerdas, dentro de clickable yo habia cambiado un valor de un monumentVo, pues **este que estaba cambiando era el del estado, por lo que cuando le hacía el .value a monumentsState obteniendo el listado de base de datos, era exactamente la misma información** que ya estaba actualizada, por lo tanto **se ignoraba y no se hacía la recomposición**. La solución:

```kotlin
// De la función del composable vamos a eliminar el seteo del parámetro isFavorite ya que vamos a delegar este comportamiento en el v¡ewModel.

Image(
    imageVector = if (monumentVo.isFavorite) {
         Icons.Default.Favorite
    } else {
         Icons.Default.FavoriteBorder
    },
    contentDescription = "",
    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
         homeViewModel.setMonumentFavorite(monumentVo)
}

// En el método del viewModel creamos la copia cuando guardamos en base de datos, asi podemos mantener nuestros variables inmutables y la vista se va a recomponer ya que son diferentes valores.

fun setMonumentFavorite(monument: MonumentVo) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        InsertMonumentFavoriteUseCase().insertMonumentFavorite(
            monument.copy(isFavorite = monument.isFavorite)
        )
        monumentsState.value = GetAllMonumentsFromLocalUseCase()
            .map { it.toVo() }
    }
}
```

Espero que esto le sirva de ayuda, que aunque puede parecer una tontería, me ha llevado un par de días investigando y preguntando.

Comment: *"Una caracteristica que tiene es que si los datos que tiene almacenados son exactamente los mismos que le estamos pasando, esta no se va a actualizar, por eso se juega con la función copy"* -> Se llama immutabilidad y hace que a la hora de detectar si un objeto tiene cambios sea muchísimo más rápido y eficaz pues puedes simplemente mirar su ID en memoria y si ambos tienen la misma son el mismo objeto. Sin immutabilidad debes comparar atributo por atributo que todo sea igual o si hay algún cambio.